# Bad Color String Error in Python Using Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, turtle-graphics

In my python program I am reading from a file and storing the contents in a list. I checked each index of the list so I know it was stored correctly. 
I am then passing a specific index to a class which contains the color blue. 
Whenever it gets to the `turtle.color`I get an error **bad color string:  "blue"**

For example: 
`Team = Rainbow(str(sequence[0]),str(sequence[1]), str(sequence[2])) //index 2 (str(sequence[2])) contains "blue"`

The I have a class

```
class Rainbow:
    def __init__(self, Rname, Rteam, Rcolor):
       self.name = Rname
       self.team = Rteam
       self.color = Rcolor

       self.Rturtle = turtle.Turtle()

       self.Rturtle.color(self.color)//here is where I get the error
```

I made sure everything is imported correctly and did some research on the this error and only got issues with bad sequence. Also, if I pass `Team = Rainbow("Jay","Blue Jays","blue")`I do not get the error.

I was wondering if someone would be able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because your colour string also contains unwanted white spaces. Change the 3rd line to `self.color = Rcolor.strip()` for example to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: there happened to be a white space issue but I had to fix the text file because .strip() didn't work

Comment: I get the same error in Python 2 for e.g. pencolor('red'). Works in Python 3.