# Can't run turtle program on macOS: "turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: blue"

Tags: python, macos, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

The program for drawing the Fibonacci spiral works on a virtual machine on Windows, but does not work on macOS and gives errors.

Here's my code:

```
import turtle
Import math


def fiboPlot(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    square_a = a
    square_b = b

    #Setting the colour of the plotting pen to blue
    x.pencolor("blue")

    # Drawing the first square
    x.forward(b * factor)
    x.left(90)
    x.forward(b * factor)
    x.left(90)
    x.forward(b * factor)
    x.left(90)
    x.forward(b * factor)

    # Proceeding in the Fibonacci Series
    temp = square_b
    square_b = square_b + square_a
    square_a = temp

    # Drawing the rest of the squares
    for i in range(1, n):
        x.backward(square_a * factor)
        x.right(90)
        x.forward(square_b * factor)
        x.left(90)
        x.forward(square_b * factor)
        x.left(90)
        x.forward(square_b * factor)

        # Proceeding in the Fibonacci Series
        temp = square_b
        square_b = square_b + square_a
        square_a = temp

    # Bringing the pen to starting point of the spiral plot
    x.penup()
    x.setposition(factor, 0)
    x.seth(0)
    x.pendown()

    # Setting the colour of the plotting pen to red
    x.pencolor("red")

    # Fibonacci Spiral Plot
    x.left(90)
    for i in range(n):
        print(b)
        fdwd = math.pi * b * factor / 2
        fdwd /= 90
        for j in range(90):
            x.forward(fdwd)
            x.left(1)
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp + b


# Here 'factor' signifies the multiplicative
# factor which expands or shrinks the scale
# of the plot by a certain factor.
factor = 1

# Taking Input for the number of
# Iterations our Algorithm will run
n = int(input('Enter the number of iterations (must be > 1): '))

# Plotting the Fibonacci Spiral Fractal
# and printing the corresponding Fibonacci Number
if n > 0:
    print("Fibonacci series for", n, "elements :")
    x = turtle.Turtle()
    x.speed(100)
    fiboPlot(n)
    turtle.done()
else:
    print("Numb
```

Here are the errors:

```
kEventMenuPopulate to menu ''
kEventMenuPopulate to menu '<Apple>'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'python'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'File'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'Edit'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'Window'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'Help'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'Help'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'Help'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu 'Help'
kEventMenuPopulate to menu ''
```

and this

```
  File "/Users/als/PycharmProjects/spiral_of_fibonacci/main.py", line 81, in <module>
    fiboPlot(n)
  File "/Users/als/PycharmProjects/spiral_of_fibonacci/main.py", line 12, in fiboPlot
    x.pencolor("blue")
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2253, in pencolor
    color = self._colorstr(args)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 2697, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/turtle.py", line 1159, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: blue
```

In macOS

[image: printing]
[image: code errors]

In Windows

[image: program without errors]
[image: printing]

I can't see problems with the code, because it runs on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad Color String Error in Python Using Turtle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602434/bad-color-string-error-in-python-using-turtle)

Comment: I don't see any problems with your color code. The problem might be with the underlying `Tk` installation on the mac. Do other color strings such as `"red"` also fail? A workaround might be to use `rgb` values instead of color strings, like `x.pencolor(0,0,255)`

Comment: By the way -- the code that you posted can't be run as is. There is a typo in the second line and it also cuts off abruptly in the middle of a string literal at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0):

After fixing the incomplete line:

```
print("Numb
```

and changing the case on the incorrect line:

```
Import math
```

this code runs fine on my Mac OS (Unix) system.  Below is my rework of your code to simplify it so I could see everything that was going on.  See if it works any better for you:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi

# 'FACTOR' signifies the multiplicative factor
# which expands or shrinks the scale of the plot:
FACTOR = 2

def fiboPlot(n):
    a, b = 0, 1

    # Setting the colour of the plotting pen to blue
    turtle.pencolor('blue')

    # Drawing the first square
    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(b * FACTOR)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.right(90)

    # Drawing the rest of the squares
    for _ in range(n - 1):
        # Proceeding in the Fibonacci Series
        a, b = b, b + a

        turtle.backward(a * FACTOR)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(b * FACTOR)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(b * FACTOR)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(b * FACTOR)

    # Bringing the pen to starting point of the spiral plot
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(FACTOR, 0)
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.pendown()

    # Setting the colour of the plotting pen to red
    turtle.pencolor('red')

    a, b = 0, 1

    # Fibonacci Spiral Plot
    for _ in range(n):
        print(b)
        distance = pi * b * FACTOR / 180

        for _ in range(90):
            turtle.forward(distance)
            turtle.left(1)

        a, b = b, b + a

# Input the number of iterations our algorithm will run:
n = int(input('Enter the number of iterations (must be > 1): '))

# Plot the fibonacci spiral fractal and
# print the corresponding fibonacci number:
if n > 0:
    print("Fibonacci series for", n, "elements:")
    screen = Screen()
    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    fiboPlot(n)
    screen.mainloop()
else:
    print("Number something or other")
```